# How to convert <ul><li> tree to JSON tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

I want to convert this list:

```
  <li>
    <a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-1" data-image="assets/images/programs/ai.jpg">Видос 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-4" data-image="assets/images/programs/ek.jpg">Видос 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-5" data-image="assets/images/programs/vs.jpg">Видос 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-6" data-image="assets/images/programs/lz.jpg">Видос 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-2" data-image="assets/images/test/woodhouse.png">Видос 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-3" data-image="assets/images/test/sterling.png">Видос 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-7" data-image="assets/images/test/pam.png">Видос 7</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-8" data-image="assets/images/test/malory.png">Видос 8</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-9" data-image="">Видос 9</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-10" data-image="assets/images/test/figgs.png">Видос 10</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="http://site.ru/cabinet/vidos-11" data-image="assets/images/test/cheryl.png">Видос 11</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

*(Also viewable as):*

```
LI
    A
    UL
        LI
            A
        LI
            A
        LI
            A
LI
    A
LI
    A
    UL
        LI
            A
            UL
                LI
                    A
                    UL
                        LI
                            A
                        LI
                            A
                            UL
                                LI
                                    A
```

To JSON tree:

```
{//li
    a: '',
    ul: [
        {//li
            a: ''
        },
        {//li
            a: ''
        },
        {//li
            a: ''
        }
    ]
},
{//li
    a: ''
},
{//li
    a: '',
    ul: [
        {//li
            a: '',
            ul: [
                {//li
                    a: '',
                    ul: [
                        {//li
                            a: ''
                        },
                        {//li
                            a: '',
                            ul: [
                                {//li
                                    a: ''
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**How to do this?**

I have this functions for recursive loop throung list, **but I not imagine how to apply them to build my JSON array:**

```
var nodeStructure = {
    pseudo: true,
    children: [] // I want to insert my JSON inside this array
};

function buildStructure(node) {
    var c = node.children;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        buildStructure1(c[i], 0);
    }
}

function buildStructure1(node, depth) {
    ++depth;
    //txt = depth + node.nodeName + "<br>";
    var c = node.children;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        //txt = c[i].nodeName + "<br>";
        buildStructure1(c[i], depth);
    }
}

buildStructure(document.querySelector('ul#divtree'));
```

How to use them in my case?

Comment: Basic recursion of looping over and building objects and arrays. select the first level, build the array, loop over the lis, check to see if it has children, if it goes go back and create the object and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source project which may help you. try this one?
https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON

Comment: It works not the way that I need (explained in my JSON example). For example I won't to print ``'li': `` key, only ``'ul': ``, ``'a': ``, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote it!** It was hard, but I have success

```
var nodeStructure = {
    pseudo: true,
    children: []
};

function buildStructure(node, parent) {
    var c = node.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].nodeName == 'LI') {
            parent.push({});
            var sc = c[i].children;
            for (var j = 0; j < sc.length; j++) {
                if (sc[j].nodeName == 'A') parent[i]['a'] = '';
                else if (sc[j].nodeName == 'UL') {
                    parent[i]['ul'] = [];
                    buildStructure(sc[j], parent[i]['ul']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

buildStructure(document.querySelector('#divtree > ul'), nodeStructure.children);
// Debug:
// document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(nodeStructure.children)+'</pre>');
```